# How to get the weekday number from std::chrono::year_month_day in C++

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono, weekday

In C++ 20, the following code will output the number (0-6) for the weekday of the input date:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    year_month_day dmy;
    cin >> parse("%d %m %Y", dmy);
    cout << format("%w", weekday{dmy}) << '\n';
}
```

How can I get that number to use in code as a numeric value so I could use it in a calculation? This has to be simple but I can't figure it out.

```
int total_score = weekday{dmy} * 10;
```

As a side note, I am really using the date (http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) library created by Howard Hinnant in C++ 17 but I believe the same question applies to both.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/weekday/encoding

Comment: @appleapple That looks like an answer to me :)

Comment: @appleapple This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew it would be simple. If you give this as an answer and you include the relevant function call in a code snippet, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::chrono::weekday::c_encoding`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/weekday/encoding) to retrieve the stored value.